# Store JSON Data on Server

Tags: xml, database, json, serialization, datastore

I am building a mobile APP which is has a form with many fields.

I am wondering if I can create a JSON Object, serialize it and send it over the wire and save it on the Server.

What is the mechanism to do that?

Are there any other / better options. I don't want to use a DATABASE.

Thanks
Rajesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out MongoDB, it was made for you.  It stores/retrieves JSON to disk in binary format. Also, it's not a relational database, it's **NOSQL**, where data is saved as JSON *document collections* rather than in tables.  There's no installation process, you just download some binaries, copy them to your server, and away you go.  Also, MongoDB drivers are available in a variety of languages.

http://www.mongodb.org/

Comment: Thanks. I am also trying Solr. I will try MongoDB and see which fits better for my project.